# How to create a counter with TWIG?

Tags: symfony, twig, operators, drupal-8, drupal-views

I have a site with Drupal 8 and I want to create a task counter with TWIG.

I use views with conditions. The counter must be incremented whether the view has a result or not.

Here is the code I just made :

```
<span class="badge badge-warning task-badge-warning">
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_produit_non_publie', 'block_1') is not empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_role_marchand', 'block_1') is empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
</span>
<span class="badge badge-danger task-badge-danger">
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_aucun_produit', 'block_1') is empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_aucune_variation', 'block_1') is not empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_commande', 'block_1') is not empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_mode_de_livraison', 'block_1') is empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_passerelle_de_paiement', 'block_1') is empty %}
    1
  {% endif %}
</span>
```

There are 2 counters :

- a "Warning" badge
- a "Danger" badge

Do you know a solution to do this ?

- The "Warning" badge must display the total number of "Warning" tasks.
- The "Danger" badge must display the total number of "Danger" tasks.

Comment: What is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`set`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/set.html) variables and then increment them:

```html
{% set warnings = 0 %}
<span class="badge badge-warning task-badge-warning">
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_produit_non_publie', 'block_1') is not empty %}
    {% set warnings = warnings + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_role_marchand', 'block_1') is empty %}
    {% set warnings = warnings + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ warnings }}
</span>
{% set dangers = 0 %}
<span class="badge badge-danger task-badge-danger">
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_aucun_produit', 'block_1') is empty %}
    {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_aucune_variation', 'block_1') is not empty %}
    {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_commande', 'block_1') is not empty %}
    {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_mode_de_livraison', 'block_1') is empty %}
    {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if drupal_view_result('boutique_page_liste_des_taches_passerelle_de_paiement', 'block_1') is empty %}
    {% set dangers = dangers + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ dangers }}
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But just a small question. In order for the counter to update I have to empty the Drupal cache. Is it possible not to cache the counter ? Thank you

Comment: I would guess that it is not your counter value that is cached but the view results.

Comment: I opened a new question for my cache problem. I have however disabled the cache in the view but that does not correct the problem :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460402/how-to-make-the-counter-ignore-the-drupal-cache

Comment: Can we update the counter using JS to avoid the cache ?

Comment: I found that https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/fr/dev/tags/cache.html and I updated my code https://pastebin.com/zc2kBpYY but I have an error in Drupal "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." my logs "wig\Error\SyntaxError : Unknown "cache" tag. dans Twig\Parser->subparse()"